# Is lodash's isEqual a viable way to improve performance in shouldComponentUpdate?

Tags: reactjs

If I have a huge amount of props/state with some quite expensive render functions, would I expect any benefit from taking this approach?

```
shouldComponentUpdate = (nextProps, nextState) => {
    let arePropsEqual = isEqual(this.props, nextProps)
    let isStateEqual = isEqual(this.state,nextState)

    if(arePropsEqual && isStateEqual){
        return false 
    }

    return true
}
```

I'm aware the generally-accepted approach is to pick through all your props/state manually and draw the conclusions yourself, but in this case there's too much going on to reliably do that.

Comment: `isEqual` performs a deep comparison so that could get very expensive and hurt performance. If that is not an issue for you then go ahead ... Keeping full control over your re renders is preferable

Comment: If there's 'too much going on' in a single set of state/props, then it sounds like you need to divide up your component's into smaller and more manageable ones. Otherwise you'll get to this point, where either you spend a huge amount of effort manually diffing 2 objects, or you just compare everything and reduce performance